# Как установить ссылку консольного приложения на библиотеку классов через командную строку dotnet?

Tags: c#, консоль, visual-studio-2019

Консольное приложение требует ссылку на библиотеку классов.
dotnet add reference ..\Pegus.ToursClassLib\Pegus.ToursClassLib.csproj
Как установить ссылку консольного приложения на библиотеку классов?[image: Решение содержит два проекта.]

Comment: Почему вы все делаете через консоль я не пойму..? У вас есть потрясающая IDE (Visual Studio), которая работает, открывается, но вы ее всячески игнорируете, будто у вас открыт блокнот и простая консолька. Что мешает вот взять, тыкнуть 2 раза по .sln файлу в правом списке, нажать правой кнопкой мыши по нужному проекту и там выбрать пункт "добавить ссылку на проект" (раздел "добавить")? Зачем консоль я вот не пойму... Вы ведь сами себе придумали сложности, нет? Ну а консоль, укажите там путь к .csproj файлу проекта, в который надо добавить, либо перейдите в папку, где этот .csproj находится.

Comment: Задание такое создать консольное приложение черед вид терминал и добавить ссылки. 2 раза по sln файлу добавить есть только создать файл, добавить новый элемент создать папку